# How to use multiple cases in Match (switch in other languages) cases in Python 3.10

Tags: python, switch-statement, match, python-3.10

I am trying to use multiple cases in a function similar to the one shown below so that I can be able to execute multiple cases using match cases in python 3.10

```py
def sayHi(name):
    match name:
        case ['Egide', 'Eric']:
            return f"Hi Mr {name}"
        case 'Egidia':
            return f"Hi Ms {name}"
print(sayHi('Egide'))
```

This is just returning `None` instead of the message, even if I remove square brackets.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/#or-patterns, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#or-patterns, https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching

Answer (score 146, accepted):

According to
[What’s New In Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching),
[PEP 636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#or-patterns), and
[the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#or-patterns),
you use a `|` between patterns:

```py
case 'Egide' | 'Eric':
```

Comment: What if you already have the list (and need to use it in more places)? Can you somehow create that `'Egide' | 'Eric'` pattern from a list? Or is it better to use an if statement in that case?

Comment: @Ruben That sounds like a better situation for an if-statement.

Comment: @Ruben You can do that with a [guard](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-conditions-to-patterns): `case name if name in male_names:`. There's more in [Blake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74187281/).

Comment: have to be careful of accidentally using (x, y) too! that matches the literal tuple, I've made that mistake so many times and always end up back on this answer..

Answer (score 29):

You can use `|` ([or](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#or-patterns)) to replace `['Egide', 'Eric']` with `'Egide' | 'Eric'`, but you can also match elements belonging to iterables or containers with a [guard](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-conditions-to-patterns), as follows:

```py
CONSTANTS = ['a','b', ...] # a (possibly large) iterable

def demo(item):
    match item:
        case item if item in CONSTANTS:
            return f"{item} matched"
        case _:
            return f"No match for {item}"
```

Comment: shouldn't `case other` be `case _`?

Comment: Hi @odigity -- It's simply an unused variable name, so you can call it anything you'd like

Comment: @blake, agreed, but the (un)official convention seems to be _ for the default case.

Comment: @TomPohl @Black there is a difference between `case other` and `case _` and it is explained in PEP 634 as well as here: https://earthly.dev/blog/structural-pattern-matching-python. The former is a capture match and binds the match to a new variable `other` while the latter is a wildcard match. If nothing else is given, both always succeed.

Comment: @interDist, agreed, but since `other` is not used in the case body, I would still recommend _.