# How to use multiple cases in structural pattern matching (switch case) in Python 3.10

Tags: python, switch-statement, structural-pattern-matching

Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642889/how-to-use-multiple-cases-in-match-switch-in-other-languages-cases-in-python-3/) question, I am trying to match an element in a list, and handle the cases accordingly. See the example below.

```py
direct_payments = ["creditcard", "debitcard"]
on_credits = ["gift card", "rewards program"]

def print_payment_type(payment_type):
    match payment_type:
        case in direct_payments:
            print("You paid directly!")
        case in on_credits:
             print("You paid on credits!")

print_payment_type("gift card")
```

I want this to print `"You paid on credits"`. I am convinced that using structural pattern matching is the most readable option in my case. Is there any way to achieve this behaviour? I cannot use `"gift card" | "rewards program"`, because I need to use the lists elsewhere.

Comment: `if/else` is what you should go with.

Comment: @matszwecja That's really a shame, because I have 5+ cases to handle and this seems like the nicest way to program it.

Comment: It really isn't, if/else will actually give you more readable code.

Answer (score 2):

- `case` needs to a pattern (the feature is called structural pattern matching after all). So we cannot include a function there (e.g. `case XX in direct_credits`.) [Thanks to matszwecja for this clarification.]
- The cases are generated by the `match` statement. So we cannot do this `case in direct_payments:`.

I could think of an application of `case` like this:

```
direct_payments = ["creditcard", "debitcard"]
on_credits = ["gift card", "rewards program"]

def find_val(value, arrays):
    for i, arr in enumerate(arrays):
        if value in arr:
            return i
    return -1

def print_payment_type(payment_type):
    match find_val(payment_type, [direct_payments, on_credits]):
        case 0:
            print("You paid directly!")
        case 1:
            print("You paid on credits!")

print_payment_type("gift card")
```

However, I do not understand why you would prefer `case` over `if/ elif/else`. You could combine your requirements easily using `and/or`.
Anything that you want to do using `match-case should be easily doable using` elif` conditions.

```
direct_payments = ["creditcard", "debitcard"]
on_credits = ["gift card", "rewards program"]

def print_payment_type(payment_type):
    if (payment_type in direct_payments) and (payment_type not in on_credits):
        print("You paid directly!")
    elif payment_type in on_credits:
        print("You paid on credits!")

print_payment_type("gift card")
```

This [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements) should be where you can get more examples of using case.

**EDIT:** gimix has a better answer.

Comment: `case` does not need to be a type - it is supposed to be a *pattern* though (the feature is called  *structural pattern matching* after all). That's why if/else is a better solution here, as OP is dealing with *conditions*, not *patterns*.

Comment: The case operator jumps to the instruction needed, while if/else must check every condition before stopping at the condition of choice.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
def print_payment_type(payment_type):
    match payment_type:
        case payment_type if payment_type in direct_payments:
            print("You paid directly!")
        case payment_type if payment_type in on_credits:
             print("You paid on credits!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ***dictionary***, like this:

```
my_dict = {'direct_payments': ["creditcard", "debitcard"],
    'on_credits': ["gift card", "rewards program"]}


def print_payment_type(payment_type):
    selected_key=next(key for key, value in my_dict.items() if payment_type in value)
    print("The selected dictionary key is", selected_key)
    match selected_key:
        case "direct_payments":
            print("You paid directly!")
        case "on_credits":
             print("You paid on credits!")

print_payment_type("gift card")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use structural pattern matching like this:

```
def print_payment_type(payment_type):
    match payment_type:
        case "creditcard" | "debitcard":
            print("You paid directly!")
        case "gift card" | "rewards program":
            print("You paid on credits!")


print_payment_type("gift card")
```

However, this might not be the most elegant option because you "lose" the `direct_payments` and `on_credits` lists.